# Is it possible to have two different sets of normals for one mesh?

Tags: shaders, normals, normal-map, toon-shading

I'm working on a material for Eevee. It has two Diffuse BSDF nodes in it, called "Toon" and "Diffuse". Toon works with actual mesh normals, then I convert shader to RGB and use Color Ramp, creating typical toon shading.
"Diffuse" supposed to use smoother normals of the same mesh and then I combine them. The final result looks something like this:
[image: A demonstration of desired result]

Here I achieved it by using an object-space normal map baked from same mesh but slightly smoothed and with normals smoothed trough *Alt+N → Smooth Vectors* repeated multiple times. However because it's an object-space map, it won't work correctly with deformations. I also tried to bake tangent-space map and use it, but the result was not satisfying:

[image: Demonstration of weird shading occurring when using tangent-space normal map]

Though I am inexperienced user and I'm not excluding that I baked it wrong or I'm using it in a wrong way or perhaps what I want to do isn't possible at all. However I would like to know if there is any other way of implementing this idea.

Here's my blend file:
[image]